# multiple buttons on a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter

I need multiple buttons on a canvas in Python Tkinter. The purpose is to draw connection lines among the buttons. My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
convas = Canvas(root)
convas.pack()
button1 = Button(text = "button 1")
button1.configure(width = 0, activebackground = "#D2D2D2", relief = GROOVE)
button1_window = convas.create_window(10, 10, anchor=NW, window=button1)
button1.update()
print (button1.winfo_geometry())

button2 = Button(text = "button 2")
button2.configure(width = 0, activebackground = "#D2D2D2", relief = GROOVE)
button2_window = convas.create_window(10, 50, anchor=NW, window=button1)
button2.update()
print (button2.winfo_geometry())
root.mainloop()
```

running this code, I always just got **button 1** in the canvas although I tried to adjust the location in the `create_window` function, and the `anchor=`. the **button 2** does not show in the canvas at all.

The two prints return:

> 62x26+10+10
>   1x1+0+0.

Based on the output **1x1+0+0**, the **button 2** seems not being rendered. what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

My mistake:

```
button2_window = convas.create_window(10, 50, anchor=NW, window=button1)
```

should be

```
button2_window = convas.create_window(10, 50, anchor=NW, window=button2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second button code in line 14 says `window=button1`. Change it to:

```
button2_window = convas.create_window(10, 50, anchor=NW, window=button2)
```

So that `button2` shows up on its window like this:

[image]